# How do I make command line arguments run with either, neither, or both arguments? - Java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I am making a selenium webdriver and I have 25 apps and 4 environments. I have them set up as enums so I can give specific command line arguments. Right now I have it working so that it takes one app and then one environment in that order. I need to be able to do something like

```
-app app1 app2 app3 -env env1 env2
```

I need it to either take no arguments, either arguments, or both arguments. This is what I have so far.

```
if (args.length == 0)
{
    LogIn.loginTest(testResults);
    DatabaseTest.testResults(testResults);
    LinkTest.linkTests(testResults);
}
else 
{
    // First choose application, then choose environment
    Application.chooseAppTest(args);
}
```

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with Selenium! You are just looking for a way to parse arguments passed to a Java app.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a library for evaluating your command line arguments, like [JOptSimple](http://pholser.github.io/jopt-simple/). They provide a nice set of examples on their [website](http://pholser.github.io/jopt-simple/examples.html) and you wouldn't have to re-invent the wheel. Adopting to your example, the following should work, according to the documentation (haven't tried it out):

```
OptionParser parser = new OptionParser("app:env:");
OptionSet options = parser.parse("-app", "app1", "app2", "app3", "-env", "env1", "env2");
```

`options.valuesOf("app")` should then return a list of "app1", "app2", and "app3".

Answer (score 0):

Without writing the code for you, here's a suggestion :

- Loop over all the arguments of `args` array.
- Make sure the first one is equals either -app or -env
- Collect into one list all the arguments from the second String in the array until you find either -app or -env
- Collect into another list all the arguments following the second -app/-env
- Don't allow -app or --env to appear twice
- Now you'll have two lists, one for the apps and the other for the envs (though they can be empty)